# How to hide softkeyboard in multiline edittext?

Tags: android

I am making small application. I use EditText to summarize all data. It shows a few times, every time has own line. User is able to write short note next to time.

I have issue with soft keyboard. I would like it to have "ok" instead of enter. I mean, it shoul not do extra line. On enter, keyboard should close.

For now, I have something like this:

```
EtNotes.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It closes keyboard, but it does extra line and that is the problem.

I have already tried to put:
    `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
in my layout xml file. Unfortunately it also didn't worked.

To sum up, I would like my keyboard don't do extra line and closes after enter button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return true in the branch where you handled the key input

Comment: Simpliest solutions always the best :) Thank You very much

Comment: Mark the question answered and accept the answer please